# Run cron for indexation every hour

Tags: magento2.3, cron

This is the first time I want to run cron for indexation every hour. I found multiple tutorials but none of them give me what I'm looking for or skip some steps.

I'm using `OVH` as a web hosting, Magento 2.3.

Help, please.

Comment: Please add more information to your question related to your requirement so one can help you here!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below documentation of OVh Web hosting to set automated tasks.

> https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/hosting/hosting_automated_taskscron/#create-an-automated-task

**Example**: Add the below code in your file you have set for schedule task:

```
//Assuming your file is in the Magento root folder.

<?php system('<path to php> <path to root>/bin/magento indexer:reindex') ?>

OR

<?php
    $command = 'php /path-to-magento-root-directory/bin/magento indexer:reindex';
    echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Also, check the below post if it is helpful!

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494242/ovh-cron-jobs-symfony-command

More, take a look at Magento documentation to Configure and run cron

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I alrady saw this, but my issue is what should I put on the the file added on ovh!

Comment: @Nouarizineb I have added an example in my answer. Add the code in your file and check if it works!

Comment: do you have any idea of the ovh php path plz?

Comment: @Nouarizineb run `whereis php` in terminal and it will show the path.

Comment: it gives me all of tha paths:php: /usr/local/bin/php.BETA /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php.ORIG /usr/local/lib/php.ini-3 /usr/local/lib/php.ini-0 /usr/local/lib/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/lib/php.ini-2 /usr/local/lib/php.ini-1 /usr/local/php5.5 /usr/local/php5.6 /usr/local/php5.3 /usr/local/php7.0 /usr/local/php7.3 /usr/local/php7.1 /usr/local/php7.2 /usr/local/php5.4 /usr/local/php7.1/bin/php

Comment: I'm using php 7.1, I put  /usr/local/php7.1?

Comment: Yes check your current version `php -v` and use it in commands.

Comment: yes I'm using php 7.1 on my magento, so according to whereis php I should put  /usr/local/php7.1 on the .php file?

Comment: @Nouarizineb Yes

Comment: please can you tell me how to run the command twice a day instead of every hour ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add new cron in your crontab

```
 0 */1 * * *  /usr/bin/php  /YourMagentoInstallation/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: where I should add this plz?

Comment: @Nouarizineb add your server crontab

Answer (score 0):

use this cron expression

```
<crontab>
            <jobs>
                <stockalert_autosend>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>stockalert/observer::backinstock</model></run>
            </stockalert_autosend>
            </jobs>
        </crontab>
```